# Raid unresponsive for a few minutes

Tags: hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I have a raid 5 on my desktop where I save my work (scripts in python or js mostly).

Sometimes when I edit a file with vim and save it, it takes a few minutes to save, in that time the vim window is unresponsive and the hdd is making write noises at full, the red led of hdd activity is also on all the time it's unresponsive. (the file is usually really small, about 200 lines or so, so it should be writen instantly)

However when I check with iotop what is using my drive so hard, I see nothing, it shows 0 kb/s on hdd i/o, but the disk keeps making noises with the light on.

Mdamd --detail and smartctl says my disks are allright.

Is this a raid misconfiguration or is some of my disk failing despite what smartctl says?

Comment: What type of disks are you using? Is it something based on SMR (Shingled Magnetic Recording)?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the power mgmt of the hard drives is set to always on...maybe one or more are going to sleep if this is just a data RAID and not your OS RAID.

Update firmware on the drives.

Use a low level disk tool to check for bad blocks on the disk.

If the above doesn't work, you can try and isolate it to one disk since you have a RAID 5.

1. Verify backup good
2. Pull out disk 1.
3. Test to see if you have the same problem.
4. Reinsert disk
5. Verify RAID has rebuilt and is good status.
6. Repeat 2 to 5 with other two disks.

Good luck and post your findings when you get a chance.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer. Few days after posting this question, one of the drives broke completely, so it was that. Thanks for the answer anyway.